# Thymeleaf template engine swallowing exceptions

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf 2.0.5 with spring 3 mvc configured as follows in webmvc-config.xml

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
   class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver"
   p:prefix="/WEB-INF/templates/"
   p:suffix=".html"
   p:templateMode="HTML5" />

<bean id="templateEngine" 
   class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine"
   p:templateResolver-ref="templateResolver" />

<bean id="viewResolver" 
   class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver"
   p:templateEngine-ref="templateEngine" />
```

The above configuration is working fine. The problem is that when an exception is thrown I see the following cryptic message in the logs:

> ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][1] Exception processing template "dataAccessFailure": Error resolving template "dataAccessFailure", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Is there a way to configure the view resolver to exclude certain patterns?

---

As per the accepted answer I changed the following bean config in webmvc-config.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" 
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver"
      p:templateEngine-ref="templateEngine"
      p:viewNames="index,questionnaires/*" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure your template resolver to only resolve certain view names by means of the template resolver's `viewNames` property. In this property you can enter several patterns (separated by commas) and use wildcards like e.g. `admin/*`.

Disclaimer, due to StackOverflow rules: I am thymeleaf's author.

Comment: I noticed in the javadocs that you can also set `excludedViewNames`

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly have an error page mapped to "dataAccessFailure" in your web.xml. Something like:

```
<error-page> 
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
    <location>/dataAccessFailure</location> 
</error-page>
```